# Верная форма числительного

Tags: числительные

Какова верная форма числительного в предложении: "полиция разыскивает двадцать два преступников/преступника" или "двадцать двух преступников"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Разыскать](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (разыскивать), ***кого-что***. Найти в результате поисков; отыскать. *Разыскать родственников, преступника. Разыскать цитату. С трудом разыскал нужную книгу. Разыскать утраченную рукопись.*

По управлению глагола необходимо использовать винительный падеж [счетного оборота](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5).

> **4.** При нормальной форме *доставить двадцать два пассажира* (в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на *два, три, четыре*, винительный падеж сохраняет форму именительного независимо от категории одушевленности) существует разговорная форма *доставить двадцать двух пассажиров*.

[§ 151. Формы винительного падежа одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных](http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxvi.html#sect151.3)

Получается:
совершенно правильно — *полиция разыскивает **двадцать два преступника*** (выслали двадцать два гражданина);
но допустимо (только в разговорной речи) — *полиция разыскивает **двадцать двух преступников*** (выслали двадцать двух граждан).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашёл: в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, четыре, винительный падеж сохраняет форму именительного независимо от категории одушевленности.